# Thunderbirds can't send via Gmail

Tags: 12.10, thunderbird, email

Everytime I'm trying to send message this error occured:

> Sending of message failed. The message could not be sent because the
>   connection to SMTP server smtp.googlemail.com timed out. Try again or
>   contact your network administrator.

I'm using automatic setup, receiving email and other inbox operation just works.

Here is my outgoing server setup:

[image][1](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/75813759/gm.png)

Comment: Try changing the server name from .googlemail.com to .gmail.com.

Comment: It didn't work either.

Comment: Have you enabled POP or IMAP within your Gmail account settings?

Comment: Yes I have, both are enabled by default, I've checked.

Answer (score 3):

## Gmail SMTP

```
Server: smtp.gmail.com **or** smtp.googlemail.com
Port: 465
Security: SSL/TLS
Password: Normal Password
```

#### Other Potential Problems

Some ISP's block outbound SMTP connections.  Typically, they will only block port 25 outbound, but it could be that your ISP doesn't want you connecting to any other SMTP servers.

Your gmail or Google Apps account must have IMAP/SMTP enabled in your [Account Settings](https://google.com/accounts).

Comment: I have tried these setting and IMAP/SMTP enabled. Didn't work. ISP problem might be the case, I guess..